# NameError: uninitialized constant when trying to run test file

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, testunit, faker

So I have written a new class for the faker gem. I want to submit a pull requests but the tests which I have written will not run due to a sneaky error.

I'm using Rubymine to run these tests becuse `rake test` does not work properly on my machine probably because `Windows` `<insert verb of choice>` (thanks bill gates).

Anyways, I can run the existing test files just fine, all of which pass. I can't however, run my test. I'm pretty sure it will pass on the faker gem's build, but the right thing to do is test.

So without further ado, here is my class:

```
module Faker
  class Shakespeare < Base
    class << self



      def hamlet_quote
        hamlet.sample
      end

      def as_you_like_it_quote
        as_you_like_it.sample
      end

      def king_richard_iii_quote
        king_richard_iii.sample
      end

      def romeo_and_juliet_quote
        romeo_and_juliet.sample
      end

      def hamlet
          ["To be, or not to be: that is the question.",
           "Neither a borrower nor a lender be; For loan oft loses both itself and friend, and borrowing dulls the edge of husbandry.",
           "This above all: to thine own self be true.",
           "Though this be madness, yet there is method in 't.",
           "That it should come to this!.",
           "There is nothing either good or bad, but thinking makes it so.",
           "What a piece of work is man! how noble in reason! how infinite in faculty! in form and moving how express and admirable! in action how like an angel! in apprehension how like a god! the beauty of the world, the paragon of animals! .",
           "The lady doth protest too much, methinks.",
           "In my mind's eye.",
           "A little more than kin, and less than kind.",
           "The play 's the thing wherein I'll catch the conscience of the king.",
           "And it must follow, as the night the day, thou canst not then be false to any man.",
           "Brevity is the soul of wit.",
           "Doubt that the sun doth move, doubt truth to be a liar, but never doubt I love.",
           "Rich gifts wax poor when givers prove unkind.",
           "Do you think I am easier to be played on than a pipe?",
           "I will speak daggers to her, but use none.",
           "When sorrows come, they come not single spies, but in battalions."]
      end


      def as_you_like_it
          ["All the world 's a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their exits and their entrances; And one man in his time plays many parts.",
           "Can one desire too much of a good thing?.",
           "I like this place and willingly could waste my time in it.",
           "How bitter a thing it is to look into happiness through another man's eyes!",
           "Blow, blow, thou winter wind! Thou art not so unkind as man's ingratitude.",
           "True is it that we have seen better days.",
           "For ever and a day.",
           "The fool doth think he is wise, but the wise man knows himself to be a fool."]
      end


      def king_richard_iii
          ["Now is the winter of our discontent.",
           "A horse! a horse! my kingdom for a horse!.",
           "Conscience is but a word that cowards use, devised at first to keep the strong in awe.",
           "So wise so young, they say, do never live long.",
           "Off with his head!",
           "An honest tale speeds best, being plainly told.",
           "The king's name is a tower of strength.",
           "The world is grown so bad, that wrens make prey where eagles dare not perch."]
      end



      def romeo_and_juliet
          ["O Romeo, Romeo! wherefore art thou Romeo?.",
           "It is the east, and Juliet is the sun.",
           "Good Night, Good night! Parting is such sweet sorrow, that I shall say good night till it be morrow.",
           "What's in a name? That which we call a rose by any other name would smell as sweet.",
           "Wisely and slow; they stumble that run fast.",
           "Tempt not a desperate man.",
           "For you and I are past our dancing days.",
           "O! she doth teach the torches to burn bright.",
           "It seems she hangs upon the cheek of night like a rich jewel in an Ethiope's ear.",
           "See, how she leans her cheek upon her hand! O that I were a glove upon that hand, that I might touch that cheek!.",
           "Not stepping o'er the bounds of modesty."]
      end

      end
    end
  end
```

Here is my test file:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/test_helper.rb')

class TestFakerShakespeare < Test::Unit::TestCase      
  def setup
    @romeo_and_juliet = Faker::Shakespeare.romeo_and_juliet
      @king_richard_iii = Faker::Shakespeare.king_richard_iii
      @as_you_like_it = Faker::Shakespeare.as_you_like_it
      @hamlet = Faker::Shakespeare.hamlet
  end

  def test_quotes
    assert @romeo_and_juliet.size == 11    
    @romeo_and_juliet.each do |quotes|
       assert !quotes.nil?
       assert quotes != ""
    end    

    assert @king_richard_iii.size == 8    
    @king_richard_iii.each do |quotes|
       assert !quotes.nil?
       assert quotes != ""
    end   

    assert @as_you_like_it.size == 8   
    @as_you_like_it.each do |quotes|
       assert !quotes.nil?
       assert quotes != ""
    end   

    assert @hamlet.size == 18    
    @hamlet.each do |quotes|
       assert !quotes.nil?
       assert quotes != ""
    end       
  end  

  def test_as_you_like_it_quote
    assert Faker::Shakespeare.as_you_like_it_quote.match(/\w+/)
  end

  def test_king_richard_iii_quote
    assert Faker::Shakespeare.king_richard_iii_quote.match(/\w+/)
  end

  def test_romeo_and_juliet_quote
    assert Faker::Shakespeare.romeo_and_juliet_quote.match(/\w+/)
  end

  def test_hamlet_quote
    assert Faker::Shakespeare.hamlet_quote.match(/\w+/)
  end

end
```

Here is my error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Faker::Shakespeare
C:/workspace/faker/test/test_faker_shakespeare.rb:5:in `setup'
    (eval):12:in `run'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 7.1.3/rb/testing/patch/testunit/test/unit/ui/teamcity/testrunner.rb:93:in `start_mediator'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 7.1.3/rb/testing/patch/testunit/test/unit/ui/teamcity/testrunner.rb:81:in `start'
```

And if you want to check out any more files in the repo that I was not the creator of, you can look at the repo [here](https://github.com/stympy/faker)

Comment: Did you add a require anywhere with your new filename? Seems that faker requires files here: https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/faker.rb#L160.  That might be a good place to add yours if you haven't.

Comment: Awesome, that is just what I needed, all my tests passed and I'm ready for a pull request. Thank you!

Comment: If you would like to make this comment into an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to require your `Faker::Shakespear` file somewhere in the code. Faker seems to have most requires here http://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/faker.rb#L160 , that might be a good place to start.